# Is this a mumps variable in action?

Tags: mumps

So in this MUMPS command, are we jumping to label `meth` in a file named by a variable called `blurfl`?  If we're not, I don't know what the percent sign is doing. There is no file called %blurfl.m in my application.

```
GOTO meth^%blurfl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have filenames that begin with % in Unix/Linux, so the file is actually named _blurfl. When the mumps system sees %blurfl, it does the translation and loads the correct file.

In this case the command is issuing a goto to the meth label in the %blurfl routine, which is actually named _blurfl.m

Comment: Actually, it's VMS that doesn't allow `%`. Unix/Linux does, but YottaDB and GT.M have kept the VMS conventions.

Comment: VMS of Digital Equipment Corporation fame, @SamHabiel??

Comment: The one and same, said to be one of the best bullet proof OS'es on the planet. Now gone!

Comment: I used to be a VAX/VMS fanboi, @SamHabiel #beerhoist